# async await not waiting for value of find to be returned in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, object, asynchronous

I am using React and this async/await method is just not awaiting for a condition to be ran for some reason. Here is my code that I have:

```
  const handlePetSelection = async (value) => {
    setSelectedPet(value);
    // Extract premium pet plan
    const premiumPlan = await value.plans.find(plan => plan.plan === 'premium');
    // For pets with more than 1 plan option, default plan to the premium plan
    if (value && value.plans.length >= 1) {
      await setSelectedPlan(premiumPlan);
    }
  };
```

It selects the plan successfully and sets it, as in I can see it in the UI it selects it. But shortly after(about 3 seconds later), the react app crashes and I get the error:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'plans')

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `find` is not an `async` method to be awaited, it is already a `sync` method.

Comment: I see. Is there any suggestions or alternatives that you can please let me know about for this to work?

Comment: Please provide code which totally supports the question. You are missing codes. and its difficult to suggest

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the array method .find is not asynchronous.

You can remove your async await call and check to make sure premiumPlan has returned something since .find will return undefined if nothing is found

```js
  const handlePetSelection = (value) => {
    setSelectedPet(value);
    // Extract premium pet plan
    const premiumPlan = value.plans.find(plan => plan.plan === 'premium');
    // For pets with more than 1 plan option, default plan to the premium plan
    if (premiumPlan && value && value.plans.length >= 1) {
      setSelectedPlan(premiumPlan);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that was the first thing I tried that didn't work, and which led me to try options like async/await

Comment: Then you'll need to post more information about what values you're passing in etc. There's no way to debug further with what you've shown. If value is actually asynchronous (e,g. it comes from an api response) then you need to async await that response and when it returns fire your handlePetSelection. But that's just presuming it's coming from an API call or some other async operation